# Combine 2 columns on 1 row using gridLayoutmanager in intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-14, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to develop an application to sort photos, based on the tinder principle.

The picture below is a screenshot of my current GUI, I want to combine the 2 middle columns on the first row so that the label for the photo to be placed in is nicely in the center.

This GUI has been developed in intellij using the gridlayoutmanager. Could someone happen to help me solve this problem?

Kind regards

Current GUI:

[image: current GUI]

Answer (score 0):

> This GUI has been developed in intellij

Don't use the IDE to generate your GUI code. Write the code yourself so you are in full control

> using the gridlayoutmanager

You are never forced to use a single layout manager. You can create multiple panels each using a different layout manager to achieve your desired layout.

> I want to combine the 2 middle columns on the first row

Create a panel. Add the "Dislike" and "Like" buttons to the panel. Add the panel to the parent panel.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.